# Order of differencing and ACF plots

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, differencing

On this website: [https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/arimrule.htm](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/arimrule.htm) I have found information that if the lag-1 autocorrelation is zero or negative, or the autocorrelations are all small and patternless, then the series does not need a higher order of differencing. If the lag-1 autocorrelation is -0.5 or more negative, the series may be overdifferenced. Does lag-1 here refers to the first lag or some "lag minus one"?

Answer (score 0):

Let the time series be $x_t$, then "lag-1 autocorrelation" is $$\rho(1)=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(x_t,x_{t-1})}{\operatorname{var}(x_t)}$$

Comment: Could you please tell me whether these time series with the 1st order of difference are already overdifferenced?

https://imgur.com/jsYTpIL

With 2nd order difference I get the same results except that the first lag is positive instead of negative. Could you explain what this means?

Comment: Hi @jnan12 it’s better be asked as a separate q. for others to comment as well.